# Angular 6 routing doesn't work when i enter url in browser

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-routing

My angular routing works when i navigate through the app but when i enter the url through browser i am unable to see the page. Stuck on this issue . when i enter the url in browser i get a json body instead of my component getting loaded
here is the controller method that i am calling:

```
 @GetMapping(value = "getTrade", produces = arrayOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
    @CrossOrigin(origins = arrayOf("*"))
    fun getTransactionDetails(@RequestParam("linearID") linearID: String): ResponseEntity<List<StateAndRef<TradeState>>>? {
        if (linearID == null) {
            ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Linear Id cannot be null.\n")
        }
        val idParts = linearID.split('_')
        val uuid = idParts[idParts.size - 1]
        val criteria = QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(linearId = listOf(UniqueIdentifier.fromString(uuid)),status = Vault.StateStatus.ALL)
        return ResponseEntity.ok(proxy.vaultQueryBy<TradeState>(criteria=criteria).states)
    }
```

here is my angular service file content from where i call this api:

```
 getSpecificTrade(linearID) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('linearID',linearID)
    let requestOptions=new RequestOptions;
    requestOptions.search = params;
    this.http.get('http://' + location.host + '/api/trading/getTrade',{
     headers: headers,search:params
   }).pipe(map((res:any)=>res.json()))
   .subscribe(
    (res) => {
     this.singleTrade=res[0];
     this.route.navigate(['/api/trading/getTrade'], {queryParams : {linearID : linearID}})
     console.log('success');     
    }
   );
   }
```

App.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {APP_ROUTES_PROVIDER} from './app.routes';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LandingPageComponent } from './Landing-Page/landing-page/landing-page.component';
import { SingleTransactionComponent } from './Landing-Page/single-transaction/single-transaction.component';
import {CordaContentService} from './Services/corda-content.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LandingPageComponent,
    SingleTransactionComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    //AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule,
    //HttpClientModule,
    APP_ROUTES_PROVIDER
  ],
  providers: [CordaContentService,{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Can someone please look into this if possible?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: hey can't i display the same page?

Comment: Yes, you can. That's what is explained on the page I linked to. Click and read.

Comment: This is server config problem. Please refer this.
[Server configuration in angular project deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration)

Comment: but there is nothing mentioned about spring boot/tomcat in these docs

Comment: But therse is nothing mentioned about tomcat/spring boot here and these examples are only for index.html but my code is some_appcomponent.html so i am supposed to do this can you help with a example?

Comment: What is your server and os?

Comment: No. But the documentation can't possibly cover every possible server tehnology on earth. What matters is that you understand that all you need to do is to make sure that your server sends the content of index.html when getting a request to any URL of your application. This can be done very easily with a Filter, for example. See https://github.com/Ninja-Squad/globe42/blob/master/backend/src/main/kotlin/org/globe42/web/IndexFilter.kt for example

Comment: spring boot server and unix/windows

Comment: but the thing is i want to return proxy.vaultQueryBy<TradeState>(criteria=criteria).states)
    } as well not just an page

Comment: I mean where did you host your project?

Comment: i will be hosting it on a linux server but first have to test it on windows because when i hosted it earlier it was giving me the same paroblem

Comment: I think you are testing it on your local pc. And your os is windows?

Comment: Are you using xampp?

Comment: yes testing it on windows and spring boot's server is tomcat

Answer (score -1):

Please make the file called .htaccess in your angular root path. And then write this code.

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```